# Is there an alternative AES schedule?

Tags: aes

I'm currently reversing an AES implementation for disk encryption. The odd thing I'm stumbled about is a key schedule where the encryption round keys are not the same as the decryption round keys (in "reversed order"). Altough the first 4 bytes, i.e. the first round key for the encryption, and the last 4 bytes, i.e. the last round key for the decryption, are the same. The other round keys are totally different.

Is there an optimization that requires the round keys to be computed in a different manner?

Comment: Are you saying that for decrypting, the round keys are in reversed order, or that they aren't (e.g. maybe in some random pattern)?

Comment: As per Thomas Pornin's answer, what you are seeing is called the "equivalent inverse cipher" and is the most common implementation of AES, as it is faster for decrypt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the [algorithm description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#High-level_description_of_the_algorithm), you see that, at a high-level, the encryption algorithm looks like this:

```
            addRoundKey(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < rounds; i ++) {
                    subBytes();
                    shiftRows();
                    mixColumns();
                    addRoundKey(i);
            }
            subBytes();
            shiftRows();
            addRoundKey(rounds);
```

The decryption algorithm will then look like this:

```
            addRoundKey(rounds);
            for (i = 1; i < rounds; i ++) {
                    invShiftRows();
                    invSubBytes();
                    addRoundKey(rounds - i);
                    invMixColumns();
            }
            invShiftRows();
            invSubBytes();
            addRoundKey(0);
```

Now, if you view the 16-byte state as a vector in space (**Z**<sub>2</sub>)<sup>128</sup>, then the ShiftRows() and MixColumns() transforms are linear, and so is the addition of a round key (addRoundKey() -- really, a bitwise XOR). Moreover, the ShiftRows() is byte-oriented, therefore it can commute with SubBytes() (since SubBytes() works on each state byte independently). Therefore, it is customary for AES implementations to combine SubBytes(), ShiftRows() and MixColumns() into a single step with 8->32 lookup tables (you need four of them, for a total of 4 kB of tables). This optimization is what the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Optimization_of_the_cipher) alludes to.

If you try to do that with decryption, in the loop above, you will see that the addRoundKey() step happens between invSubBytes() and invMixColumns(), which is inconvenient. The solution is to move the addRoundKey() one step down, but then the round key must be modified to account for the move (in simple words, if you add the round key *after* the invMixColumns(), then you must add a round key that has been already "invMixColumnsed"; it works because of linearity).

In that case, decryption becomes:

```
            addRoundKey(rounds);
            for (i = 1; i < rounds; i ++) {
                    invShiftRows();
                    invSubBytes();
                    invMixColumns();
                    addRoundKeyAlreadyInvMixed(rounds - i);
            }
            invShiftRows();
            invSubBytes();
            addRoundKey(0);
```

With that new algorithm layout, the invShiftRows(), invSubBytes() and invMixColumns() steps are again together, and can be optimized into a single set of lookup tables. However, this requires the "inner" subkeys (all but the first and last one) to be preprocessed with invMixColumns() so that the computations still work.

I believe this is what you observe in the implementation you are inspecting.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to reverse engineer AES as its algorithm is already publically available.  The algorithm is supposed to be so good that even though its inner workings can be (and indeed are) publically known, it is still extremely difficult to break.  I think the difficulty you may be running into is that the round keys are used in reverse order when decrypting (if my understanding is correct).  After re-reading your question, it appears you are saying the round keys are not in reversed order.  It could be that this particular vendor made a change to their implementation of the AES algorithm, which is not particularly recommended.

For an overview of AES see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

AES is thoroughly described in FIPS-197.  You will probably find pages 18 (round keys) and 25 (pseudo code including round keys) pertinent:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf